# How to extend ng-bootstrap components (NgbTab)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I have to add a loader for tab component in `ng-bootstrap`.

Here is the code for `ng-bootstrap`

```
 <ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="Home">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Home Content</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
 <ngb-tab title="Profile">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Profile Content</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Contacts">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>Contacts Content</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I need to show a loader when content is loaded with delay.

Iam not sure how to extend this component.

Is there any way to extend this component to add loader for each tab ?

Please suggest me the best ways to do this.

Comment: Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: I think that it's only put your loader inside each ng-template. But your e.g. looks like more to a kind of navigation. If it's, use simple css to create the tabs